# ChaiJs not present on window in Phantomjs-node injectJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, chai

I'm trying to inject some scripts into a page that I'm loading into PhantomJs using the phantomjs-node bridge.

When I inject MochaJs into the page, I can evaluate and the `window.mocha` object is available.  But when I inject chaiJs, the `window.chai` object isn't available.

I've verified that the injectJs call passes a `true` status into the callback, indicating that the script was successfully injected, and I've also verified that `window.chai` and `window.mocha` are available immediately after injection in a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gMzjavJqpNDNeYipmBHG?p=preview

I even tried using `page.includeJs('http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/1.10.0/chai.min.js')` to ensure there wasn't a diff in the cloudflare cdn version and the npm install version I have, still isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
page.injectJs(nodeLibDir + '/chai/chai.js', function(){
                //page.injectJs(nodeLibDir + '/mocha/mocha.js', function(){
                    page.evaluate(function(){
                        //window.callPhantom(window.mocha.constructor.name);
                        window.callPhantom(window.chai.version);
                    }, function(){
                        console.log('finished');
                        page.close();

                        res.json({status: status});
                        res.end();
                    });

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the page I was testing w/ is using requireJs to load some other libraries and was therefor causing chai to not attach itself to `window`.  Tried with a different page that is not using requireJs and it works as expected.  SMH.